# hive 0.14 update and delete queries configuration error

Tags: hadoop, hive

In apache `hive 0.14` we can update and delete queries by supporting `ACID` configuration:

```
hive.configuration:
hive.support.concurrency – true
hive.enforce.bucketing – true
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode – nonstrict
hive.txn.manager – org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager
hive.compactor.initiator.on – true (for exactly one instance of the Thrift metastore service)
hive.compactor.worker.threads-1
```

But I get the following error when I use hiveQL `show databases`:

```
as@ubuntu:~$ hive
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/as/hive/lib/hive-common-0.14.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties<br>
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.<br>
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/as/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]<br>
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/as/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]<br>
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.<br>
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]<br>
hive> show databases;<br>
FAILED: LockException [Error 10280]: Error communicating with the metastore<br>
hive> exit;
<br>
```

Please help me fix error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let add it in hive-site.xml:

```html
    <property>  
    <name>hive.in.test</name>  
    <value>true</value>  
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely either your db server or your hive metastore is not running. Try this.

```
mysqld    # or pg_ctl start -l logfile   or whatever your db start command
```

Then ensure the metastore is running

```
nohup hive --service metastore &
```

**UPDATE** from OP  "not enough freespace"

Take a look at

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

and see if it is 100% utilized.  Reference:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/198639/cannot-reinstall-mysql-in-11-10-error-theres-not-enough-space-in-var-lib-my

Comment: i think we have a problem with this configuration:
hive.txn.manager – org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager
if i delete this line i can start and use hive.
so i don`t think hive metastore is not our problem
you can show more hint for me?

Comment: i used command:
mysqld<br> ; 
hive --service metastore & ->>>>
and i get error:not enough free space(i have 5.7 GB free)
any other help?please

Comment: Updated answer.  I have helped a bit here, no?  Maybe you might consider to upvote - even if not accept yet?

Comment: My system is not enough-this is a system notification-not mysql notification.When i used command :hive --service metastore & >>> a warning system notification that not enough space,i am not understand that command creat a metadata which need 5.7GB on my computer

Comment: Please separate the mysqld command and the hive --service command on two separate lines. We need to be sure which one of the commands is causing the issue.   The error is NOT about trying to use 5.7GB for metadata . It may be due to a particular mount point (NOT / ..) having too little space.

Comment: metadata_db of hive is in my home folder /home/$USER.I not stored hive metadata in mysql so the problem is not in mysqld.when i used command and saw the system monitor the directory / is used 100%

Answer (score 1):

The thread owner is correct. Setting 
hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager

causes connection error to metastore (in my case metasdtore is SAP ASE and has multiple databases on it)

Went back and set hive.txn.manager to default
hive.txn.manager= org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DummyTxnManager

and recycled both metastore and hive server again and all worked!

Sounds like concurrency does not work or something extra needs to be done!

Comment: But we need DbTxnManager to use ACID support for hive right??(the hive ACID guide says that we need it)