# Hive Server2 ACID transactions not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, hiveql

I am using Hadoop-2.6.0 secured with kerberos. Installed hive server2 1.1.0 version with **derby** database as connectionurl, enabled security and enabled Authorization. When enabling [transaction configuration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Configuration), I am getting the below exception and cannot execute any queries;

**Exception**

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: LockException [Error 10280]: Error communicating with the metastore (state=42000,code=10280)
```

**Logs**

> [Error 10280]: Error communicating with the metastore
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.LockException: Error communicating with the metastore
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager.getValidTxns(DbTxnManager.java:300)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.recordValidTxns(Driver.java:927) 
>   Caused by: MetaException(message:Unable to select from transaction database, java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'TXNS' does not exist.

So i have created a below property in hive-site.xml file as mentioned in a blog [here](http://sanjivblogs.blogspot.in/2014/12/transactions-are-available-in-hive-014.html)

**Configuration**

```
 <property>
      <name>hive.in.test</name>
      <value>true</value>
 </property>
```

If i set the above property then getting the below exception where i am struck and unable to solve it. I cannot run any query even **use mydb;**

**Exception**

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NullPointerException null (state=42000,code=40000)
```

**Logs**

> Error executing statement: 
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NullPointerException null
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:315)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:103) 
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.TxnHandler.checkQFileTestHack(TxnHandler.java:1146)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.TxnHandler.(TxnHandler.java:117)

I need a solution to work ACID transactions in Hive Server2. I found two related questions but not solved my issue.

[hive 0.14 update and delete queries configuration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470633/hive-0-14-update-and-delete-queries-configuration-error)

[Hive Transactions are crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867368/hive-transactions-are-crashing)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your hive mysql metastore db with hive-txn-schema-0.14.0.mysql.sql as follows..

mysql> SOURCE /usr/local/hadoop/hive/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/hive-txn-schema-0.14.0.mysql.sql;